# Executing powershell script

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a question i wrote a powershell script so i have name.ps1, but i have troubles for executing it, i mean i could debut it with windows powershell (ISE), by just adding the code to it and run ... but how do i execute it different?

When i open ordinary windows powershell (so NOT ISE) and i type there script.ps1 file.csv
i get this kind of error:
[image]

This is the code that i have, maybe im not proper initiating the script in my code i dont know:

```
param ([string]$Csv)

function GetHelp() {

$HelpText = @"

DESCRIPTION:

NAME: Add-STUser
Adds Users from the User Csv File

PARAMETERS: 

-Csv         The Csv file Used by the script (Required)
-help        Prints the HelpFile (Optional)


The Csv File is built up in the following way:


Firstname, Surname, Email

"@
$HelpText
}

function Get-Csv ([string]$Csv) {

    $CsvFile = Import-Csv $Csv

    $CsvFile | ForEach {

        Add-User -Firstname $_.Firstname -Surname $_.Surname -Email $_.Email
    }
}


function Add-User ([string]$Firstname, [string]$Surname, [string]$Email) {

    # Set up AD Connectionstring

        # Get A Unique Password

        [string]$Password = Generate-Password
        $username=$Firstname.substring(0,1).toLower() + $Surname.toLower()
        # Create User in AD

        $container =[ADSI] $Connection
        $User = $container.Create("User", "cn="+$username)
        $User.Put("sAMAccountName", $username)
        $User.Put("givenName", $Firstname)
        $User.Put("sn", $Surname)
        $User.Put("mail", $Email)
        $User.Put("displayName", $Firstname + " "+$Surname)
        $User.SetInfo()

        # Set Random Pwd and Enable Account

        $User.PsBase.Invoke("SetPassword", $Password)
        $User.PsBase.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
        $User.pwdLastSet = 0
        $User.SetInfo()

        # Write Pwd to File

        $FileName = "PasswordList " + (get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d") + ".txt"

        "$Firstname, $Surname, $username, $email, $Password" | Add-Content $FileName

        Write-Host "Added User: $username" -ForegroundColor Green


    # Set Check Variable to False

    $Password = $Null
    #$Script:sAMAccountNameDoesntExist = $False
    #$Script:distinguishedNameDoesntExist = $False
}



if ($help) { 
    GetHelp 
} elseif ($Domain -AND $Csv) {
    Get-Csv  -Csv $Csv
} else {
    GetHelp
}
```

So with other words i need to execute that script with only 1 param (path to csv file)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you even read the message you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Powershell, unlike cmd, current directory (.) is not in PATH.

So to run scripts or executables in the current directory, you have to prefix with `./`

So you will have to do

```
.\script.ps1 file.csv
```

**If you look carefully at the error message, at the bottom, Powershell is giving a suggestion that you have to do so.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Powershell you want to execute a script from current location, like in *nix systems. So call the script like the error message hints:

```
./myScript.ps1
```

or

```
.\myScript.ps1
```

You can also provide full path to the script

```
c:\what\ever\is\the\path\myScript.ps1
```

The script/directory names are not case sensitive.

Comment: yes it works, but an other problem, i cant start then my function :(